# Adding Distro Information from lsb_release to Script

Tags: bash

Want to run a bash script that installs software and repos after a fresh install of a distro. I have a script that will work for debian based distros. Would like to add to the script that will take the distro from lsb_release and start the correct install commands. Is lsb_release the right choice for this? I assume I can grep the DISTRIB_ID and use that to start the next part of the script. I may be coming to this from the wrong direction. Any advice? Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can work with `lsb_release -d` to extract the description of your currently installed distribution, `lsb_release` may not be installed in some non-debian based distros.

Instead, you can look in `/etc` for a file ending with `-release`, which contains your OS information. For example, from my Ubuntu 15.10, the following is what I have:

```
alexander~$ cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu 
DISTRIB_RELEASE=15.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=wily
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 15.10"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="15.10 (Wily Werewolf)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 15.10"
VERSION_ID="15.10"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

Notice `ID`, which contains your current distribution, and `ID_LIKE`, which contains the distro your distribution is based on (in my case, ubuntu, which is based on debian). From this, you can extract the values of ID and ID_LIKE by grepping as follows:

```
cat /etc/*-release | grep "^ID=" | grep -E -o "[a-z]\w+"      # get ID value
cat /etc/*-release | grep "^ID_LIKE=" | grep -E -o "[a-z]\w+" # get ID_LIKE value
# If the -o option is not available for grep in your system, use awk instead
```

Within your script, you can initialize variables to the above statements, like:

```
current_distro=`cat /etc/*-release | grep "^ID=" | grep -E -o "[a-z]\w+"`
close_distro=`cat /etc/*-release | grep "^ID_LIKE=" | grep -E -o "[a-z]\w+"`
```

Then you can determine the appropriate install commands by checking `"$current_distro"` or `"$close_distro"` within your script.

Comment: Thank you very much. That helped. ID and ID_LIKE are much better choices.

Comment: You're welcome. And as [os-release - Operating system identification](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/os-release.html) describes them, ID/ID_LIKE are more `suitable for processing by scripts or usage in generated filenames`.